# Error while installing nfs-kernel-server in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apt-get

I am getting the following error message while trying to install `nfs-kernel-server` in my Ubuntu Server 10.04.4 LTS.

```
Setting up nfs-common (1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing nfs-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nfs-kernel-server:
 nfs-kernel-server depends on nfs-common (>= 1:1.0.8-1); however:
  Package nfs-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-common
 nfs-kernel-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried searching on Google, but couldn't solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

There's a bug filed for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1023382

What I ended up doing was a

```
apt-get remove --purge nfs-common
apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

and then put my config files back in place and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have accidentally stumbled now upon same error in the debian 9...
so maybe someone also can find it useful ...

And I have solved this by additionally removing rpcbind service and reinstalling it again

```
apt-get remove --purge rpcbind nfs-common &&  apt-get install nfs-common
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in bash

```
xxxxx@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

This will install nfs-common. Then go back and try to install your nfs kernel server. If you have installed nfs-common then run the following command and paste the output

```
xxxxx@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -L nfs-common | grep /etc/init.d/
```

Answer (score -1):

None of these options worked for me, what did work for me was going into "Disks - gnome-disk-utility", selected the partition that would not mount, selected "Options", "Edit Mount Options", I switched off "User Session Defaults", selected "OK", then pressed the ">" button to mount without errors. Hope this helps someone else out there. - Ubuntu 23.10